# Методы. Проблема с преобразованием

Tags: c#, winforms, методы

Не получается вывести переменную в TextBox после обращения к методу. Что делать?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int n = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            n = Even(x);
        textBox1.Text = n.ToString;
    }
```

Выдает ошибку на n.ToString

Comment: textBox1.Text = n.ToString();

Answer (score 4):

ToString - это метод, а используетe как переменную. Правильно так: ToString();

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 1;
    int n = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        n = Even(x);
        textBox1.Text = n.ToString();
    }

}
```